# Erro ao imprimir caractere acentuado em C!

Tags: c, impressão, caracteres

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <locale.h>
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese_Brazil");
int Quantidade_De_Clientes, i;
float Saldo_Total, Media_Total;    
printf("Qual a quantidade de clientes do banco ? ");
scanf("%d",&Quantidade_De_Clientes);
while (Quantidade_De_Clientes <= 0 || Quantidade_De_Clientes > 10)
{
    printf("\nQuantidade de clientes invalido\nDigite novamente a quantidade de clientes ? ");
    scanf("%d",&Quantidade_De_Clientes);
}
int Numero_Da_Conta[Quantidade_De_Clientes];
float Saldo_Do_Cliente[Quantidade_De_Clientes];
for (i = 0; i < Quantidade_De_Clientes; i++)
{ 
    printf("\nQual o numero da conta do cliente ? ");
    scanf("%d",&Numero_Da_Conta[i]);
    printf("\nQual o saldo da conta do cliente ? "); 
    scanf("%f",&Saldo_Do_Cliente[i]);
    Saldo_Total += Saldo_Do_Cliente[i];
}   
Media_Total = Saldo_Total / Quantidade_De_Clientes;
for ( i = 0; i < Quantidade_De_Clientes; i++)
{
    if (Saldo_Do_Cliente[i] > Media_Total)
    {
        printf("\n\nO cliente com a conta do banco de numero %d com saldo igual a %5.2f esta acima da media do saldo dos clientes do banco que é %f ",Numero_Da_Conta[i],Saldo_Do_Cliente[i],Media_Total);
    }
    else if (Saldo_Do_Cliente[i] < Media_Total)
    {
        printf("\n\nO cliente com a conta do banco de numero %d com saldo igual a %5.2f esta abaixo da media do saldo dos clientes do banco que é %f ",Numero_Da_Conta[i],Saldo_Do_Cliente[i],Media_Total);
    }
    else if (Saldo_Do_Cliente[i] == Media_Total)
    {
        printf("\n\nO cliente com a conta do banco de numero %d com saldo igual a %5.2f esta com o saldo igual a media do saldo dos clientes do banco que é %f ",Numero_Da_Conta[i],Saldo_Do_Cliente[i],Media_Total);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Estou com problemas para imprimir na tela caracteres acentuados, pesquisei e nas pesquisas ensinam a fazer dessa maneira, porém, os caracteres continuam a sair mal formatados(outros caracteres) na impressão. no '''setlocale''' já tentei vários outros parâmetros, porém nenhum outro funciona.

Comment: Inclua o sistema operacional na pergunta porque isso faz diferença na hora de responder. Se for Linux ou macOS, você deve checar o locale atual do seu sistema (no meu Linux, 'echo $LANG' mostra 'C.UTF-8') e checar se o seu fonte está usando o mesmo encoding (no Linux o comando 'file arquivo.c' diz se o fonte é UTF-8 ou ISO 8859-1, o encoding tem de bater com o do sistema)

Comment: meu sistema operacional é o Windows! como prosseguir ?

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa (para visualizações futuras dessa questão) é usar a tabela ASCII caso seja apenas necessário o output correto e esse não dependa do input. [Tabela ASCII](https://web.fe.up.pt/%7Eee96100/projecto/Tabela%20ascii.htm)

O código a seguir exemplifica output dos caracteres acentuados em português

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int i;
char c[11];
c[0]=133; /* à */
c[1]=160; /* á */
c[2]=198; /* ã */
c[3]=131; /* â */
c[4]=130; /* é */
c[5]=136; /* ê */
c[6]=161; /* í */
c[7]=147; /* ô */
c[8]=162; /* ó */
c[9]=228; /* õ */
c[10]=163; /* ú */
for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
    printf("%c",c[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Caso o código acima não funcione, pode ser que o console/terminal do seu sistema não use a codificação ASCII.

Usando a [Tabela ANSI](http://www.mhavila.com.br/topicos/mm/char_maps.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int i;
char c[11];
c[0]=224; /* à */
c[1]=225; /* á */
c[2]=227; /* ã */
c[3]=226; /* â */
c[4]=233; /* é */
c[5]=234; /* ê */
c[6]=237; /* í */
c[7]=244; /* ô */
c[8]=243; /* ó */
c[9]=245; /* õ */
c[10]=250; /* ú */
for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
    printf("%c",c[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```